# Does there exist a Schauder basis for the space of complex valued continuous functions on a compact topological space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

The question is as above. Is there a Schauder basis on the space? If there exists, can one construct such a basis explicitly? With the domain as a compact interval, Weierstrass theorem and polynomials pass through my mind...but I cannot proceed on. Could anyone help me?

Comment: For $C[a,b]$, the monomials $x^n$ do not form a Schauder basis. But it still has one, with the most commonly quoted one being the Faber-Schauder basis. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet#Haar_system_on_the_unit_interval_and_related_systems) article (Faber-Schauder section) for more.

Comment: There is also a basis consisting entirely of polynomials (it's not the monomials under any ordering). Note that when a Banach space has a basis it has uncountably many "distinct" ones in the sense that there is not automorphism taking one basis from this family to another. References: Topics in Banach Space Theory, A short course in Banach space theory